# urllib2 python exception in Ubuntu when loading a https json file

Tags: python, django, urllib2, urlopen

I'm trying to load a json file but it's throwing an exception:

```
<urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>
```

This is my code (I executed it on the shell for testing/debugging purposes):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> uri = 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search?q=camisas%20columbia'
>>> req = urllib2.Request(uri)
>>> resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) Bitnami's Django Stack 1.4.3-0 virtualized on VMWare.

But, I was curious and tried the same exact code in my host machine (Windows 7 64-bits) where I also have **THE SAME EXACT VERSION** of python installed and guess what... it worked flawlessly.

Here's the windows output:

```
C:\Users\Kevin>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
>>> uri = "https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search?q=camisas%20columbia"
>>> req = urllib2.Request(uri)
>>> resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> resp.read()
'{"site_id":"MLA","query":"camisas columbia","paging":    {"total":43,"offset":0,"limit":50},"results":    [{"id":"MLA445360462","site_id":"MLA","title":"Ca
misa Columbia Silver Rider Hombre Tecnolog\xc3\xadas De Omni-dry" [...]
```

How can I fix this issue in Ubuntu? I have tried changing the user agent and stuff in the request but the result was always the same on Ubuntu.

Also tried manually copying the json file and uploaded it to dropbox and ran the same code as above but with the dropbox url and it worked flawlessly on both systems.

Hope you guys can help me, this is driving me crazy and my whole project depends on that freaking api :(

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Can you open your json on ubuntu machine with any browser.

Comment: This is probably a network infrastructure problem. Does the webserver you're querying require authentication? Maybe the virtualization is playing tricks on you. Can you open the URL in a Browser within Ubuntu?

Comment: @Denis My ubuntu machine doesn't have GUI, it's just console. I tried downloading the json file with WGET and it worked (it downloaded the file). It's weird...

Comment: @ThorstenKranz Nope, it doesn't require authentication, try it yourself: https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search?q=camisas%20columbia I tried downloading it with WGET in ubuntu and it  downloaded it without problem.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, also with Ubuntu 12.04 in VMWare running on a Windows box, and for me it worked like a charm.

BTW: Who did "-1"? What is the problem?

Comment: @ThorstenKranz the weird thing is that I suspected it was an SSL/HTTPS issue but the json located in dropbox works and is using https! So I don't know who to blame...

Answer (score 1):

I found the root of the issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/965371